# How to create an ASPX file from a SQL Server Express 2005 database

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-express

I know this is a low-level question but, not being a database person, I have limited knowledge of how to go about this. I have SQL Server Express 2005 installed on a Windows 2003 R2 server. The guy who was in my position created a lot of databases and built .NET applications (?) that run our Intranet and a couple websites.

One of the things I have been tasked with is to use one of his databases to build an 'equipment check out' database. The database has already been built and I have no problem viewing the tables and information already stored. My problem is that everyone remembers an area on the Intranet where this information was available (I'm fairly new). Two brief reports were also done to show what was available and 'who had what' equipment.

I have spent the past few days trying to figure out how to make this work and am coming up empty. The guy who was here before is uncooperative. In the grand scheme of things I don't feel like this is important or that I should be working on it but my superiors do. They are getting impatient about this.

Can anyone please help me figure this out? I just need a way to represent the data that is already in the database and create a page that can be dynamically changed on our company Intranet -- as well as the two reports. I'm familiar with creating static HTML pages but this is out of my league. I can see in other areas there are aspx and aspx.cs files but I don't know much about them -- I'm more of a Network Admin person.

The information needs to be conveyed in a manner that a 3rd grader would understand (without making me feel like TOO much of an idiot...)

Anybody willing to help?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is a database - how do you want to "create" webforms from that??? What are you looking for?? Do you have your webforms and you need to know how to load the data?? Not very clear what your goal is....

Comment: If there used to be functionality like this on the intranet before, what happened to it? Someone must know. Not really fair to task you with creating an ASP.NET web application from scratch if you're not a developer.

Comment: Marc_s: I see there is a database and I see the results of it in the web pages it created. There is a disconnect there, I agree, but I don't know how to connect the dots. My goal is to create something that USED to be there from just a database.

Comment: Anders: I don't know what happened to it. I know it USED to be there but, like I said, the guy who built it is not interested in helping (phone calls and e-mails unanswered). I'm on my own.

Comment: I do not think this is a real question.  Lets not feed the troll

Comment: Chad: I assure you this is very real. I've already had to provide status on where I am on this project. I don't like losing my deoderant on something fairly insignificant as this is, from my point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that everyone remembers
>   an area on the Intranet where this
>   information was available (I'm fairly
>   new). Two brief reports were also done
>   to show what was available and 'who
>   had what' equipment.

I would focus on finding the location on the site where this information used to be located. Check your User's browser history, search file contents for keywords etc. This would take a lot less time than learning to program websites.

**Updated Answer Based on your comments:**
Since you are really "stuck" with this problem, and you are only dealing with two users, I would suggest solving the problem with a reporting package instead of giving the HR and Accounting person a web based solution. I just think there is too much to learn in such a short amount of time. I'm assuming by your description that the users are not editing the information on the site, just viewing it, right?

Grab a 30 day free download of Crystal Reports:

http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports/index.epx

It's a nice reporting package, with a very large user base. You won't have any trouble finding learning resources (Web/books).

Comment: We weren't co-workers. I've been here 2 years and he had left the company about 4 months before I was hired. I have found the folder where the files live -- there are 2 ASPX files and 2 ASPX.VB files. I can try and post or upload somewhere if that would help.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant check with your Users- the "Everyone" in "everyone remembers". My suggestion to you still stands. Unless your employer is OK with you taking months to pick up a new skill, don't bother trying to fix this issue. You weren't hired as a software developer, were you? If you slap something together that you found on the internet, your employer is going to make you own that solution, and all the problems/enhancements that come with it.

Comment: Thank you, I could not agree with you more! However, the principals in the company DO want me to put something together and they DO want me to 'own' it. The 'Everyone' to which I'm referring are an HR person and an Accounting person -- who have less knowledge about such things than I do. I'm the IT person for the company and I have fought the 'politics' of this issue the best way I know how. I've got to come up with something, no matter how bad it appears (and I hate saying it that way).

Comment: bzarah: I used Crystal Reports in a previous job so I have some experience with it. Unfortunately, it does need to be dynamic. People who have permission to do so need to be able to add/remove information from the database through the page created. I was going to use CR for the two small reports that need to go with this.

Comment: Mr_Thomas, good luck sir. Keeping both HR and Accounting happy on any given day is hard enough. :) If you are really going to tackle this problem on your own, I wouldn't suggest spending any more time posting on Stackoverflow. This site is best when you have a simple, tightly scoped question that doesn't take long to explain. I would instead search the site for suggestions on books and sites that will help you learn to do MS.Net Web Development. You should be able to get started without having to pay much. Visual Studio Express Web is a free download: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Answer (score 1):

See if this can help you.
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/videos/create-a-data-driven-dynamic-web-page

Comment: I watched the video and it was very informative, but it was about Microsoft WebMatrix (which looks cool, by the way) and I don't have time at this point to learn something different. (I had to laugh when it said 'enter some code here' -- that's the code I was trying to learn)

Comment: @Mr_Thomas the only easy ways you can create a web site in .net is through Visual Studio or Web Matrix. You have to pick one.

Comment: I'll pick Visual Studio. Do you know what the difference is between "Visual Basic 2008" and "Visual Web Developer 2008" express editions? I've actually dealt with some visual basic (.vbs) files for command-line network operations.

Comment: Just for edification, I am installing 'Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition'. I hope this is what I need.

Comment: I installed VB2008 Express without incident. Now, when I try to open my SQL database, it tells me 'a different process may be using the file'. I just pointed it to where my .MDF file is located. Should I start a new thread for THIS issue?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas, I would recommend VS 2010 Express Edition, you can't go for the file .mdf file as SQL Express Service is connected to it, you have to connect to SQL, passing ServerName, User and password, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you being a non-programmer (or more if IT Pro), you just want to have the UI representation of data which is already designed in database.

Assuming that you have some basic knowledge about Visual Studio and related, I can suggest to go up and read/watch about the Dynamic Data. Below URL should give you a good start for this.

More information on this is available here http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata

Comment: Just to clarify, I have NO knowledge of Visual Studio. I have used 'SQL Server Management Studio Express' to view the database and tables. I'll take a look at the links provided.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be pretty hard for you to make this. But still if you must then here's a simple way to do it:
1. Open Visual Studio
2. Create a new Web Site (File -> New -> Web Site)
3. Open Server Explorer window (View -> Server Explorer)
3.1 Create new data connection (here provide info similar to when you log into Sql Server Management Studio)
3.2 Click on the Tables node listed under your data connection and drag this table to a web page.
4. Save everything and hit F5.

If everything goes fine you'll see the contents of the table in a web page inside a grid. Try this and wherever you get stuck put a comment under this answer. We'll try to sort this out.

Comment: I don't seem to have anything called 'Visual Studio' by itself. I have a 'debugger' and a 'debugger configuration manager' under the "Visual Studio 2005" folder. I'm going to see if it's something I can download.

Comment: If the guy before you "created" the application on this machine then it should have Visual Studio. Otherwise you can request your IT Admin guy to install it. If there's nobody to do it then download Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition (but I think it's 70-100 MB if I'm not wrong).